# Two-body system with spring and acceleration of center of mass confusion

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, harmonic-oscillator, spring

So we have a following system, which is undergoing a simple harmonic motion:

[image]

Lets say our $m_1$ mass compresses spring on rightward side, and $m_2$ thus, strecthes spring on rightward side, so, you can imagine that whole system kind of moves in right direction. Now center of mass here obviously has some acceleration, here, but I couldn't figure out any external force here (friction is considered to be absent). So its creating s confusion here. Moreover, I have read that such situations can't be solved (for any parameter) with conservation of linear momentum, with reason because, $a_{com}\ne0$.

I am having a similar doubt regarding a similar situation as depicted:[image]Here I had to find, Time period of the SHM, and solution had included that linear momentum can't be conserved due to same reason $a_{com}\ne0$, rather it was solved with angular momentum conservation. Here also, same confusion arose regarding acceleration of center of mass

Please help in removing the confusion, any help is massively appreciated!

Comment: Please clarify - are you considering the two masses to be held such that the spring is stretched and then they are let go?

Comment: why would you think the center of mass is accelerating?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's choose an inertial frame of reference for the system.

The force from the spring on the masses is proportional to its deflection: $F = ku$. If it is compressed at any time $t$, (the opposite if it is strechted), $m_1$ has an acceleration to the left and $m_2$ to the right. $$\frac{dv_1}{dt} = -\frac{F}{m_1}$$ and $$\frac{dv_2}{dt} = \frac{F}{m_2}$$ Integrating both sides:
$$v_1 = \frac{dx_1}{dt} = -\frac{F}{m_1}t + v_{01}$$ and $$v_2 = \frac{dx_2}{dt} = \frac{F}{m_2}t + v_{02}$$

Integrating again:

$$x_1 = -\frac{F}{2m_1}t^2 + v_{01}t + x_{01}$$
$$x_2 = \frac{F}{2m_2}t^2 + v_{02}t + x_{02}$$

Multiplying each equation by the respective mass and adding them:

$$m_1x_1 + m_2x_2 = (m_1v_{01} + m_2v_{02})t + m_1x_{01} + m_2x_{02}$$

The LHS is the position of the COM from the perspective of the inertial frame by definition. In the RHS, we have a constant multiplying $t$ plus another constant.

So the COM of the system is moving with a constant velocity for any inertial frame.

Answer (score 0):

> so, you can imagine that whole system kind of moves in right direction

If the center of mass (COM) does move in the right direction, it has to be at constant speed. That's because there are no external horizontal forces acting on your system, so it is not possible for the COM to be accelerating.

Hope this helps.